# Expressões regulares limitar número

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

Com expressões regulares, como limitar um número mínimo e máximo de uma string.

Tenho um campo, onde posso adicionar de `1` a `4` caracteres. Mas os números deverão ser de 1 a 1000. Dessa forma não pode começar com `0`.

Como fazer com expressão regular:

```
^([^10]{1})[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: @Diogo ambiguidade de cenários de uso assim não sendo possível determinar qual a alternativa ótima pois JS Regex e PHP PCR possuem diferenças de sintaxe, exemplo `[^]`. O AP deveria deixar apenas uma ou outra linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Se é pra limitar um numero o mais fácil seria:

```
if ($numero > 0 && $numero <= 1000) {
    //Algo aqui é executado
}
```

Tem que ser maior que zero e menor ou igual a 1000.

**Não precisa de [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para algo tão simples assim**, agora se o objetivo de fato é aplicar a regex em outro "grupo" precisa analisar o que você deseja de fato e qual string você deseja fazer o match/casar, porque eu posso dar uma resposta de regex que na verdade vai quebrar a lógica da tua regex atual que já existir.

Algo que seria o básico para funcionar com regex, do qual eu **não posso garantir** que vai quebrar outras regex suas dentro de uma mesma, seria:

```js
var testes = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 200, 300, 900, 1000, 2000, '01000', '01', '0100'
];

for (var i = 0, j = testes.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(`Valor: ${testes[i]} retorna:`, valida(testes[i]));
}

function valida(input)
{
    return /^([1-9]\d{0,2}|1000)$/.test(input);
}
```

O `[1-9]` verifica se o valor começa de 1 até 9, ou seja, nunca pode começar com zero

O `\d` verifica se é numero, equivale ao `[0-9]`, enquanto a parte `{0,2}` verifica se a sequencia é numero, o `0` antes da vírgula indica que não precisa ter nada já depois da vírgula `,2` indica que tem que ter no máximo 2 dígitos (o `[1-9]` seria o outro "digito")

Então o que esta antes de `|` deve `[1-9]\d{0,2}` indica que são aceitos "strings" de 1 a 999 e depois do `|` é o valor `1000`, como solicitado na pergunta, de 1 a 1000

Comment: Quem negativou poderia apontar aonde falhei na resposta? Se tiver algo errado desejo saber para melhorar ou corrigir o que escrevi. Grato!